# How to place an image next to bmatrix?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am currently using this but the matrix is too much to the right. I want to shift it up and to the left without changing textwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{k3.png}
\caption{Fig 3}
\label{fig:Fig 3}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{equation*}
{p} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\alpha_{1,2} \alpha_{1,3}  \\
(\alpha_{1,2}+ \alpha_{2,3})\alpha_{1,3}  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{v_1} \\
p_{v_2} \\
p_{v_3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of transforming your code snippet into a compilable MWE (minimum working example).

Answer (score 1):

after repairing of inconsistency in your code and correct all errors (missing code lines), i obtain:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders). is this what you looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{k3.png}
\caption{Fig 3}
\label{fig:Fig 3}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\[
{p} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\alpha_{1,2} \alpha_{1,3}  \\
(\alpha_{1,2}+ \alpha_{2,3})\alpha_{1,3}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{v_1} \\
p_{v_2} \\
p_{v_3}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

or with use `tabularx` instead of `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{k3.png}
&
\[
{p} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\alpha_{1,2} \alpha_{1,3}  \\
(\alpha_{1,2}+ \alpha_{2,3})\alpha_{1,3}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{v_1} \\
p_{v_2} \\
p_{v_3}
\end{bmatrix}
\]      \\
\caption{Fig 3}
\label{fig:Fig 3}
&
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, i thought about this option, but then left as op selected because to me unknown reason. i will correct this as you suggested